# Filter in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I fill combobox with database values with this:

```
    public void fillcombo()
    {
        using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
        {
            myDatabaseConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select Description from LibraryCongressClassificationOutline", myDatabaseConnection))
            using (SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (sqlreader.Read())
                {
                    string Desc = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Description"));
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(Desc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How I will filter data when i type in comboBox and automatically display all data in comboxSelection something(don't know what it is called) without clicking this [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play with AutoComplete:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx